# How do you find the right PCB?

Tags: pcb

This is a stupid question but I don't know much about electronics. I was wondering how one would find the correct PCB for their project? For example, if I wanted to make a portable USB charger, how would I find the PCB for it? I have seen a lot of those project kits but obviously there isn't one of those for every project in the world.

Comment: You would generally design the PCB yourself and have a fab house make it for you (or etch it at home).  Or, pay me lots of money to do it for you.

Comment: ... or Olin, or Andy, or Nick.

Comment: Or if those guys seem suspiciously inexpensive, talk to me.

Comment: If Olin ever sounds suspiciously inexpensive you're talking to someone else of the same name :-). [If he sounds extremely good value for money considering the superb result and astounding attention to detail then you almost certainly have the right one].

Comment: Yeah, just kidding- as well as the years you-know-where I've met Olin and seen his work.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you would design the schematic and convert it to a PCB design in a program such as Eagle, KiCAD, Altium, or ExpressPCB (There are hundreds of options out there). Then, from the program you export the GERBER files (basically files showing each layer in detail, where the holes need to be drilled, where the solder mask needs to go, etc) and send them to a board house, who would actually make the board for you.

For example, here is one of my first projects--it's a small prototyping board for a PIC microcontroller. First I drew the schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Then I used it to design the PCB by drawing traces
based on where the wires in the schematic go:

[image: PCB]

I sent that design to a friend of mine who manufactures PCBs and there you have it--a PCB ready for assembly!

Comment: and if you dont have a friend there are PCB manufacturers who will ... for a price... its not that expensive if you dont mind waiting...

Comment: This is correct, I got lucky. It's always good to make friends and have connections ;)